# Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, swt

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:450)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:388)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1249)
 at org.eclipse.compare.CompareViewerSwitchingPane.setFocus(CompareViewerSwitchingPane.java:363)
 at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.setFocus2(CompareEditorInput.java:860)
 at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor.setFocus(CompareEditor.java:499)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setFocus(PartPane.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.setFocus(EditorPane.java:127)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setFocus(PresentablePart.java:190)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:94)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:270)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:275)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.handleMouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:345)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder$3.mouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:179)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Comment: Some info about what you where doing or when it happens would be appreciated, even if it's not very useful to find the problem :)

Comment: I doubt a simple stack trace is enough to figure out what was going on.  Other helpful info may include Eclipse version #, OS type and version, what you were trying to do at the time, whether the issue is occurs consistently or sporadically, and what stuff you've already tried to solve this yourself and what the results of those steps were.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you made widget.setFocus(..) over a widget variable referencing a previously dispatched widget (widget.dispose())... Check what you are assigning to the var...